# How to bind uuid to a model after saving

Tags: php, laravel

i'm using this traits in my models

```
namespace App\Traits;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

Trait UUID 
{
        protected static function boot()
  {
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($model) {
       $model->id = (string) Str::uuid();
    });
  }
 }
```

and i'm using it in my model

```
//app/Hospital


use UUId;
```

In my form request i'm saving the model after assigning some values

```
$hospital= new \App\Hospital();

    $hospital->name = $this->name;
    $hospital->email = $this->email;
    $hospital->password = bcrypt($this->password);
    hospital->save();
    var_dump( $hospital->id);
```

The output is zero even though in my database it's a different uuid. So how to bind created uuid to the model

Comment: Have you tried `->refresh()` on the model to get a fresh model instance from the database?

Comment: What is the type of `id` in db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that your observer is running, as the record in your database has a UUID.

The issue is that the instance of your model where you call `save()` is somewhat decoupled from where you are attaching the UUID.

By this I mean that the `UUId` trait has no way of updating the instance of the model you already have in your controller. In fact, it will only have the properties on it that you've actually set (i.e `name`, `email`, `password`).

Amend your `var_dump()` to `var_dump($hospital->fresh()->id)` and this will return a freshly hydrated version of the model from the database. 
Alternatively, add a `refresh()` in between your `save()` and you `var_dump()`:

```
$hospital->save();
$hospital->refresh();
var_dump( $hospital->id);
```

Comment: when i dump the $hospital->id i get int(0) but when i dump($hospital) i get the right id but the attribute is protected 

`["original":protected]=>
array(5) {
["id"]=>string(36) "a158b7c0-07c8-4ec9-900a-fba758403f58"
}
["attributes":protected]=>
array(5) {
["id"]=>
string(36) "a158b7c0-07c8-4ec9-900a-fba758403f58"
}`